# Delete item from JList in a different thread than EDT

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am trying to delete an element from a JList while looping through a for loop. To find out which element I want to delete, I do a comparison of a tooltip I have defined, and delete only that element.

```
public static void removeElement(JList list, String idx){
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
    JLabel actual;
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++){
        actual = (JLabel) model.get(i);
         if(actual.getToolTipText().equals(idx)){
             model.remove(i);
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

This function is declared in the main class, and accesses swing elements, also declared as static.
The function is then invoked by another thread:

```
public class threadExample extends Thread{
    //...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Main.removeElement(OIS.listElement, graphicalID);
    }
    
}
```

When executing this exception comes up, BUT only sometimes.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
    t java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:497)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListModel.getElementAt(DefaultListModel.java:90)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:265)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:378)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:301)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthListUI.update(SynthListUI.java:78)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:797)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:246)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:865)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1890)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

From what I have read, I cannot make the removal within the for loop like I am doing, but I can't find any alternative. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

The problem is not with the removal process, but because I am performing the operation in a different thread than EDT.

Comment: Is `removeElement()` called from the Event Dispatch Thread? Can you show how and where it is called?

Comment: Look like you make your changes outside of Swing main thread (aka EventDispatcherThread, aka EDT). To solve your problem you should move your manipulation with `ListModel` into a Runnable implementation and call it using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Comment: Please also provide a [mcve] so we can easier understand and reproduce your problem. In this case we can provide a solution for your code.

Comment: @maloomeister I have edited the question with how the method is called.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy The way I'm calling the method, means I have to throw a runnable every time I want to perform the removal?

Comment: Why are you using a Thread? Typically updates to the GUI are done based on some user event in which case the code will be executed on the EDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that you are calling removeElement in a different thread than EDT you should use:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { removeElement(....); }
```

for asynchronous execution, or

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> { removeElement(....); }
```

if you want to wait for the method to complete before going on.

Comment: Thank you it worked! That was the problem.
By the way, I do the add to model the same way. Why is it only the remove that generates the exception?

Comment: @RafaelSá when you add you increase the size of the JList, so even if AWT sees the wrong, smaller size, it will not go out of the bound, but every time you change the model of a GUI component you must do it in the EDT thread.